# How to hide my API Key in a POST request?

Tags: node.js, api, dom, backend, hide

I want to hide my API key when I am making a post request from my browser. I need to input a number plate and send the request to the API and the API responds me with details about it. I have managed to get this working with a GET request to another API by using nodeJS but I can't manage to make it work with a post request. Keep in mind the request needs information from my input field in the browser which is the registration number of the vehicle to send me information back about it.

Here is my function in my browser JS file.

```
const searchBtn = document.getElementById("search-btn")


function startFetch() {
  let plate = document.getElementById("plate").value

  let reg = {registrationNumber: `${plate}`}

  fetch(`https://driver-vehicle-licensing.api.gov.uk/vehicle-enquiry/v1/vehicles`, {
    method: 'POST', 
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'x-api-key': `my key is here`,
 },
   body: JSON.stringify(reg),
 }) 

 .then(response => response.json())

 .then(response => {
   console.log(response);
 
 })    

 .catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
 });
```

};

searchBtn.addEventListener("click", startFetch);

Any help and method would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean hide? You want to obfuscate it? Using encryption? Should you even send the key in the first place?

Comment: @ytan11 I just want it to be hidden from the Front-End. I've made relays in the past for GET request but the key gets sent in the URL and I know well how to add it to the URL. With post requests I can't seem to grasp where my key should be.

Comment: I assume your api key is a secret. Your secret should never be in the front end in the first place, because you cannot hide anything in the front end. You are sending your source code to the client everytime they use the front end. Sending the secret in HTTP no matter how is a very bad idea.

Comment: You should instead hide the secret in the backend, and relay every request that need the secret to use the said backend. You might also want to consider not saving the secret on the source code. That you can consider using encryption, environment variable, or some sort of key vault/secret manager, etc.

Comment: @ytan11 Thank you. That is what I am trying to do, but I struggle to find how to send the body from the front end to the back end. The body will be a JS Object. Any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone in the same boat. I have managed to achieve what I want.

Client side JS file:

```html
function startFetch() {
  let plate = document.getElementById("plate").value
  let reg = {registrationNumber: plate}

  fetch(`http://localhost:3000/v`, {
    method: 'POST', 
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(reg),
  }) 
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);      
  })    
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```

And the backend using Express, NodeJS, body-parser and axios

```html
require("dotenv").config()
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const axios = require('axios');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static("src"))

//Env vars
const API_URL = process.env.API_URL
const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY

app.post('/v', (req, res) => {
  const body = req.body;

  // Make a request to the backend API
  axios.post(API_URL, body,
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        'x-api-key': API_KEY
      }
    }
  )
  .then((response) => {
    // Return the response from the backend API to the client
    res.send(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle any errors
    res.status(500).send(error);
  });
});


app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('API proxy server is listening on port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already sending the body.

A very minor modification to you code:

```
function startFetch() {
  let plate = "abc123";

  let reg = { registrationNumber: `${plate}` };

  fetch(`https://driver-vehicle-licensing.api.gov.uk/vehicle-enquiry/v1/vehicles`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "x-api-key": `my key is here`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(reg),
    }
  );
}

startFetch();
```

You can see your `api-key` in the header (though you should never send secret via http):
[image: request header]

Then in the body (in chrome they call it payload):
[image: request body]

Comment: Many thanks, my friend. You are correct. I was sending the body but not actually using it in the backend.

Comment: I don’t mind my friend but my account is still new and wouldnt let me cast votes until i have 15 reputation.